# Show a 0 when reputation changes, not nothing

Tags: feature-request, reputation, design, achievements-dialog

I noticed that my reputation on two sites changed, yet I saw so number on the trophy icon.

[image: Trophy icon]

After opening it, I saw that I had a +2 and a -2 in recent changes.

[image: +2 and -2]

This is somewhat confusing, as my reputation changed but it seems like it didn't because there is no number.

I'd like to see a 0 be shown if there were any reputation changes, but they equaled 0.

Comment: Note that you also get no number if net change is negative.

Comment: @Charlie that's not really the point, OP asks to highlight the trophy icon so that they would notice reputation changed.

Comment: +0 might be confusing, but a good alternative might be to turn the icon green like when there's no rep change but a badge is awarded

Comment: I sometimes get a -2 in my reputation which seems to have no explanation other than a previous +2 edit post have have had the post deleted.  It would be nice to know that was the cause and not an unreported downvote somewhere.